# How do I do eager loading for multiple associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, query-optimization, eager-loading, public-activity

I am using [public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) and one of my partials I have this call:

```
<%= link_to "#{activity.trackable.user.name} " + "commented on " + "#{activity.trackable.node.name}", node_path(activity.trackable.node.family_tree_id,activity.trackable.node) %>
```

That is executed by this call:

```
      <% @unread_act.each do |friend| %>
        <li><%= render_activity friend %> </li>
      <% end %>
```

That instance variable is assigned in my `ApplicationController` here:

```
  before_filter :handle_nofications

  def handle_nofications
    if current_user.present?
      @unread_act = Notification.where(owner_id: current_user).includes(:trackable => :user).unread_by(current_user)
    end
  end
```

I am using the gem Bullet, to find N+1 queries and the feedback I get is this:

```
N+1 Query detected
  Comment => [:node]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:node]
N+1 Query method call stack
```

I initially got that message for `:trackable` and for `:user`. Both of which I am now eager loading via `includes` within that assignment statement.

However, I have no idea how to go 3 levels deep on an eager loading - rather than just two.

Given that the node is called like `activity.trackable.node.name`, I imagine some appropriate eager loading assignment would look something like:

```
  @unread_act = Notification.where(owner_id: current_user).includes(:trackable => [:user, :node]).unread_by(current_user)
```

But the error I get is this:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError at /
Association named 'node' was not found on Node; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

I even get that when I simply do:

```
@unread_act = Notification.where(owner_id: current_user).includes(:trackable => :node).unread_by(current_user)
```

So I suspect something else is going wrong here.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1**

See Node & Notification models and associations below.

`Node.rb`

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked except: :update, owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }

  belongs_to :family_tree
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :media, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :node_comments, dependent: :destroy
```

`Notification.rb`

```
class Notification < PublicActivity::Activity
  acts_as_readable :on => :created_at
end
```

Comment: Show your models. What are `Notification`'s `trackable` associaton? What are `Node`'s associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the correct way to approach this is by using an array on the `trackable` attribute like so:

```
@unread_act = Notification.where(recipient_id: current_user).includes(:trackable => [:user, :node]).unread_by(current_user).order("created_at desc")
```

The main part is:

`includes(:trackable => [:user, :node])`

This seems to have worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

This will hopefully be fixed in rails 5.0. There is already an issue and a pull request for it.

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17479

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8005

I have forked rails and applied the patch to 4.2-stable and it works great for me. Feel free to use it, even though I cannot guarantee to sync with upstream on a regular basis.

https://github.com/ttosch/rails/tree/4-2-stable